# How to package a Vaadin Add-On created by Maven archetype "vaadin-archetype-widget" version 8.1.x?

Tags: maven, vaadin, add-on, vaadin8

I have successfully implemented some `ColumnRenderer` classes for adapting java.time types for display with Vaadin Grid. See [source code here](https://bitbucket.org/basil_bourque/timecolumnrenderers) if curious.

Now I would like to publish these as an Add-On in the [*Vaadin Directory*](https://vaadin.com/directory). I read [these directions in the Vaadin guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/gwt/gwt-addons.html), but they seem incomplete and outdated.

- There is discussion of exporting from Eclipse which is not relevant to me (using IntelliJ) and is probably old-school now that Vaadin team has moved to thorough support of [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven).
- The "Manifest" is mentioned but not documented with no mention of file name nor file location. No documentation on format or individual values.
- I found a manifest file `MANIFEST.MF` in my Maven-created project, but it is in a format of key+colon+value while the manifest shown in that documentation seems to be XML format. Which format is currently correct?
- My found `MANIFEST.MF` file contains variable names such as `${Vaadin-Addon}` and `${Vaadin-License-Title}` and `${Implementation-Version}`. Where are these defined?

Comment: This is just a brainstorming 'cause I haven't had the need to build myself an add-on so far, but if I had to guess, I'd say the ${Vaadin-XXX} should correspond to properties in your pom file, and during the build process they'd get replaced in the resulting manifest. I'll see if I can dig up some more info...

Comment: I did find this page, [*Vaadin Add-on specification 1.0 final*](https://dev.vaadin.com/wiki/VaadinAddon), but not sure if it is current or not, and it is not thorough.